# grails famfamfam plugin http 404 error

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my grails application I am using the spring-security-core:1.2.7.3 plugin with the famfamfam:1.0.1 plugin.

When I click on a link that takes me to the web application (and I previously selected the rememberme check box) it takes me to a secured page but no famfamfam images are displayed. In Firefox I can see the following error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/static/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1/images/icons/user_suit.png;jsessionid=AB8FFF32A22F98573537A965694936AC"
```

Is there any way that I can prevent the 'jsessionid' from being appended to images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this link for a response from the plugin owner: https://github.com/xiaochong/zkui/issues/118.

The issue seems to relate to the resources plugin.

My workaround was to use a blank image in the zk item:

```
`<z:menuitem label="Home" height="80px;" top="40px;"
href="${createLink(uri: '/')}" image="/images/blank.png" class="menu_house"/>`
```

And then use a class to add the menu image:
    `.menu_house {
    background-image: url("../images/house.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    }`

I hope that helps to save someone time in the future.

Comment: This issue is now fixed in ZKUI 0.5.7: https://github.com/xiaochong/zkui/issues/118